# Problema con Asset Catalog en Visual Studio 2019

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2019, xamarin.ios

Ya estoy en el proceso de publicar mi App iOS en App Store, estoy trabajando con Visual Studio 2019 y mi proyecto es un Cross Platform. sin embargo, Apple Developer me la rechaza y recibo un correo de parte indicándome lo siguiente:

*We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "[mi proyecto]". Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

ITMS-90546: Missing Asset Catalog - Your app is missing the asset catalog file in '[mi proyecto]'. For more information see http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev10510b1f7.*

He intentado agregar el jodido Asset Catalog de mil formas y nada parece funcionar, por el momento lo tengo agregado desde la configuración que tiene Visual Studio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi Info.Plist tengo lo siguiente:

```
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconName</key>
            <string>AppIcon</string>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>20x20.png</string>
                <string>29x29.png</string>
                <string>40x40.png</string>
                <string>40x401.png</string>
                <string>40x402.png</string>
                <string>58x58.png</string>
                <string>58x581.png</string>
                <string>60x60.png</string>
                <string>76x76.png</string>
                <string>80x80.png</string>
                <string>80x801.png</string>
                <string>87x87.png</string>
                <string>120x120.png</string>
                <string>120x1201.png</string>
                <string>152x152.png</string>
                <string>167x167.png</string>
                <string>180x180.png</string>
                <string>1024x1024.png</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>XSAppIconAssets</key>
    <string>Media.xcassets/AppIcons.appiconset</string>
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?
¿Qué me hace falta?

Comment: Agregaste las imágenes en el Asset de Xcode?

Comment: No, ¿Cómo hago eso? D: